# How to input password to git push from script without using SSH keys?

Tags: git, tags, ssh, hudson, build-automation

I need to write a script that can push a tag from a build server to a git server WITHOUT USING SSH KEYS.

More people have access to the build server than to the git server, so SSH keys won't work because then anyone could push to the git server without specifying their own credentials.

The script will be run from Jenkins/Hudson, which prompts the user for a username and password when it begins the build, then passes them as environment variables to the script.

The problem is, I can find no way to force git to accept the password programmatically.

I tried:

```
echo %password% | git push
```

as well as

```
git push < tempfilewithpassword.txt (not that writing the password to a temp file is a good idea anyway).
```

But in both cases git still prompts for the password.

UPDATE: I also have tried a python script, redirecting stdin and stdout, no luck, still get the prompt.

UPDATE: Additionally I tried Expect for Windows, which does NOT get a prompt, either in the console OR in Expect itself (I.E. Expect never sees any output from git, it just times out eventually).

Any suggestions?

NOTE: Let me clarify, because people are really getting hung up on using SSH keys.

Requirements:

- The credentials should be specified at the beginning of the build (Jenkins accepts them, and passes them to my script).
- The credentials last ONLY for the duration of this single build.
- The credentials can change from one build to the next.

As far as I know, NOTHING that involves setting up SSH keys will satisfy this (unless I require the user to upload their SSH key when they initiate the script, which is not convenient).

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is on windows, so it's a .bat script.

Comment: I don't see why SSH keys wouldn't be an option. What do you mean by 'anyone could acces the git repo as my user'?

Comment: Note that the people with access to the server not only can access the git repo as your user, but they also will have access to your password (as you'll need to store it on the shared server). Using a password actually makes the situation *worse*, in multiple ways.

Comment: @Piskvor: I understood that he wouldn't store the password, but let the user type it in on demand.

Comment: If I store an SSH key on the build server (the one pushing to the GIT server), then anyone can go to that build server, make other changes to its local repo, and push them up to the GIT server.  By "my user" I mean if I set up the SSH key on my account on the GIT server, but that isn't actually super relevant (setting up a different user just for the build server to access the GIT server doesn't solve my problem).  All I want is to do a single push without leaving any credentials set up afterwards.

Comment: Piskvor, I think you misunderstand.  I am not storing the password at all (other than in memory by the process), it is typed in at the beginning of the process and is never saved to disk.

Comment: You could use an encrypted key which needs a passphrase, but this only shifts the problem to providing the passphrase. Maybe `ssh_agent` could be a solution here, though it is normally used interactively.

Comment: Other than this, the usual way to provide interactive input to a process which tries to read from the terminal (like `ssh` here) would be `expect`. No idea if/how this works on windows, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anyone to have push access to your git repository, create a separate user on the build server which no-one but you has access to, and ensure its home directory is readable only by yourself. This user will be used when you want to do tagging or other pushing to your repository from the script. Now you can set up ssh keys normally.

However, I have to wonder, why does it have to be the build server that initiates the push/pull? Can't a script on the machine which contains your repo initiate it? Then the whole issue would be moot, surely?

Comment: I want the build server to tag the repo whenever it makes a build (which is why it has to be the build server that initiates the push).  If I initiate the build, it should push with my credentials.  If my coworker initiates it, it should push with his.  This precludes any ssh key setup unless we all have separate build systems with our own SSH keys set up on them, which is a bit silly.

Comment: Firstly you don't need separate build systems. The home directory can be essentially empty and the build system can be located in a directory to which all devs have access. To prevent simultaneous builds, you can use a simple file-based locking mechanism in a script (I don't know whether Hudson has any feature that does this for you). Secondly, now that I understand better what you want to do, I can suggest the `ssh -A` option, which forwards your ssh-agent connection to the user on the server, meaning you can keep private keys on developer machines. Still need separate users on the server tho

Comment: The problem with that is that devs don't SSH into the build server.  Hudson/Jenkins (sorry, the project just changed names a couple months ago and I'm being inconsistent about using the new vs old name) has a web-based interface.